# mono for android - dynamically add a layout to a scrollview

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, scrollview

I want to add a layout dynamically into a ScrollView. I tried everything I found in google and here, but no chance! Most of them causes "Object Reference" error. Here's one of the codes:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);    
View view = new View(this);
view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MYLAYOUT, null);
MYSCROLLVIEW.AddView(view);
```

But it causes the "Object reference not set to instance of an object".

And after that, I want to use the controls (views) inside MYLAYOUT, for example:

MYLAYOUT.textView1.Text = "example";

Comment: Where do you get the `Exception`? Why do you instantiate a `View` and then discard it right after?

Comment: I get the error at MYSCROLLVIEW.AddView(view); I debugged the code and it seems at this line the "view" object is null!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is cheat a bit and add my dynamic layouts inside an existing layout inside the ScrollView. Here's an example with a HorizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="739dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalMessageScrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/messageHolder" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and then in my code I use the following:

```
LinearLayout messageListView = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.messageHolder);

foreach (var object in objects) {  
    // create your dynamic views here.      

    View view = new View(this);
    view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MYLAYOUT, null);

    TextView internalTextView= view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.internalTextView);
    internalTextView.SetText("Hello world!", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    messageListView.AddView(view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That helped! But now, how can I access the new view's elements?! For example I have a textview in child and I want to setText for it.

Comment: Edited to include your `view` with a TextView example in that view.